# Reaching Tab (TabPane) from another class controller Java (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, tabs

I have a ViewController class and a TabController class. TabController extends ViewController.

In the ViewController I make the Tabs dynamically and I would like to change the name of the Tab at some point. I am always getting Null Pointer...

ViewController class

```java
public class ViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;
    @FXML
    private Button addNewTabButton;

    private Integer count = 1;

    private SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        selectionModel = tabPane.getSelectionModel();
    }

    @FXML
    public void createNewTab(){
        Tab newTab = new Tab();
        try {
           String id = count.toString();

           newTab.setText("New Tab");
           newTab.setClosable(true);
           newTab.setId(id);
           newTab.setContent(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Tab.fxml")));
           count++;

        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
            tabPane.getTabs().add(newTab);
       selectionModel.selectLast();
    }

    public void setTabText(String text){
        selectionModel.getSelectedItem().setText(text);
    }
}
```

TabController class

```java
public class TabController extends ViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button setTextButton;

    @FXML
    private void fooBar(){
        setTabText("fooBar");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }
}
```

I am always getting NullPointer on the line: setTabText("fooBar"); (TabControllerClass)

The problem is exist if I want to reach the setTabText() method from the TabController class. (There is no error when I am calling the setTabText() within the ViewController).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I recommend studying up more on inheritance. Though you're calling `setTabText()` from a class that extends `ViewController`, your `TabController` class does not **have** a `selectionModel` object. You declare a variable for it in `ViewController`: `private SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel;` but never instantiate it within `TabController`. Basically, you do not inherit all the code from a parent class; you only get instance fields and methods.

Comment: To add to what @Zephyr wrote: specifically `TabController` does not invoke `ViewController` initialize method. See my detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

To followup what is going on, add a simple print message to `ViewController` initialize method:

```
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        selectionModel = tabPane.getSelectionModel();
        System.out.println("ViewController initialized");
    }
```

When you use `ViewController` it prints out as expected.
When you use `TabController` it does not. This explains why `selectionModel` is not initialized, and why you get NPE.

One solution is to have `TabController` initialize its super :

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    super.initialize(url, rb);
}
```

Here is a simple [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate it *

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test1 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane page = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("test1.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**test1.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TabController">
   <center>
      <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <Button fx:id="addNewTabButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#createNewTab" text="Button" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Simplified controllers:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class ViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;
    @FXML
    private Button addNewTabButton;

    private int count = 1;

    private SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        selectionModel = tabPane.getSelectionModel();
        System.out.println("ViewController initialized");
    }

    @FXML
    public void createNewTab(){
       Tab newTab = new Tab();
       String id = String.valueOf(count++);
       newTab.setText(id);
       newTab.setContent(new Text("Tab number "+id));
       tabPane.getTabs().add(newTab);
       selectionModel.selectLast();
    }

    public void setTabText(String text){
        selectionModel.getSelectedItem().setText(text);
    }
}
```

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class TabController extends ViewController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        super.initialize(url, rb); //comment out this line to cause NPE
    }
}
```

---

* Consider posting mcve when asking. It makes helping easier and quicker.

Comment: Thank you, but this is already working, now I want to achive, that I would like to give text to the tab, when it is already created.
So, I have 1 more button, which should be in the TabController, since I have a text in TabController, what have to be the name of the tab.

Comment: I mean this solutions outcome is almost the same then mine.

I want to achive, that I would like to give text to the tab, when it is already created. So, I have 1 more button, which should be in the TabController, since I have a text in TabController, what have to be the name of the tab

Comment: This is not new question... this is my original question